# Jupyterlab: Is it possible to change cell colors depending on a metadata tags?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I use Jupyter Lab (2.0.1) notebooks for creating exercises and exams. The files contain both the questions and the solutions.
I marked the cells of the solutions with a "Solution" tag. When exporting with nbconvert I can now choose between output with or without solutions:

```
nbconvert  --to html --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags=['Solution']
```

What I am missing: I would have displayed all solution cells in **inside** JupyterLab marked with a color frame (or colored background).
So you can easily distinguish during editing normal cells from cells with solutions. See picture.
Does anyone have an idea how something like this could work?

[image: jupyterlab tag example]

Answer (score 0):

I have at least found a solution for exporting a jupyter file.
It is described in the documentation of nbconvert:

See https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html#Templates-using-cell-tags

Solution: create a template file "solution.tpl" with the following structure:

```
%%writefile solution.tpl

{% extends 'full.tpl'%}
{% block any_cell %}
{% if 'Internal' in cell['metadata'].get('tags', []) %}
    <div style="border:solid red 3px">
        {{ super() }}
    </div>
{% elif 'Solution' in cell['metadata'].get('tags', []) %}
<div style="border:solid green 3px">    
        {{ super() }}
    </div>
{% else %}
    {{ super() }}
{% endif %}
{% endblock any_cell %}
```

By calling

```
nbconvert --to html Exercises.ipynb --template=solution.tpl
```

all cells with the tag "Solution" are drawn with a green frame. (cells with tag "Internal" with red frame).

[image: GreenFrame for Cells with Tag]

Instead of several complete frames you can also use

```
<div style="border-left:solid green 4px">
```

for a green left bar. This looks more tidy when using several consecutive 'Solution' cells.

[image]